# Excel VBA run time error 450 from referencing a range directly rather than through an intermediate variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a Run Time Error 450 when I try to reference a value in a range directly, but if I use an intermediate variable it works.  I do not understand why so I am worried I will get the error again at some point in the future without knowing why.

I have tried using a With ... End With block and it still does not work when I reference the range directly.

This code gives the error

```
Public Sub Test_PT()
Dim lol As String

    lol = Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable2").RowRange(2, 1).Value
    MsgBox (lol)

End Sub
```

While this code works fine

```
Public Sub Test_PT()
Dim lol As String
Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable2").RowRange
    lol = rng(2, 1).Value

    MsgBox (lol)

End Sub
```

I do not know why it works in the 2nd code block but not in the first.  I have tried variations of which level to set an intermediate variable.  If I create a pivot table variable and set this appropriately, the code runs fine, but if I create a worksheet variable and try to reference the same range using the worksheet variable it does not work.

While I can get this chunk of code working by using an intermediate variable, I really want to understand WHY I need to do this in case it comes up in other contexts.

Comment: The `RowRange` property returns a `Range` object, but *it doesn't take any parameters*  Untested, but I'd guess `lol = Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable2").RowRange.Cells(2, 1).Value` would work fine

Comment: I tested it myself, and the error was that there were too many arguments. Tried to declare a `PivotTable` variable and it worked like `lol = PvT..RowRange(2, 1).Value`

Comment: @TimWilliams that's exactly OP's code on the first try, and it doesn't work. Tried myself and It didn't work either.

Comment: @Damian - yes that solution works too - but try doing it with a worksheet instead of a pivot table and you still get an error, so just reducing the number of arguments doesn't seem to be the answer.  I will try Tim's idea of adding the Cells object

Comment: @TimWilliams - no that doesn't work either just adding the Cells object

Comment: @Damian - if the issue is too many arguments, do you know what the rules are around the number of arguments allowed?  I will google it, but thought you might already know

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I don't... I tend to use variables to short the code... makes it easier to read and code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RowRange property returns a `Range` object, but *it doesn't take any arguments*, so you can't pass any in.

```
lol = Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable2").RowRange.Cells(2, 1).Value
```

works fine for me, as does

```
lol = Worksheets(1).PivotTables("PivotTable2").RowRange()(2, 1).Value
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, that works and - most importantly - I understand why.  I am not sure why adding the Cells object did not work when I tried it (after you first suggested it), but it is working now.  How did you find out that RowRange does not take arguments?  It was not clear to me from MS docs - but however you found out, I appreciate it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivottable.rowrange if there were parameters they would be listed here. Note it's not always obvious what you can do  - for example the `Range.Cells` property has no explicit parameters, but because `Range`'s default property is `Item` you can do (eg) `Cells(1,2)` but in this case it's really `Cells.Item(1,2)`