# VBA Object doesn't support this property or method when adding an object to a method

Tags: excel, vba

I have created in VBA class that contains a collection of objects. When I try to add objects via a method that I have created I'm getting:

> "438 - object dosen't support this property or method vba"

even if the method exist on my class.

myCronCol is an instance of the CronCol class defined here:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Call InstanceProfiler.AddInstance(Me)

   Set myCol = New Collection


 End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    On Error GoTo Class_Terminate_Err
    DoEvents
    Call InstanceProfiler.RemoveInstance(Me)
    Exit Sub
Class_Terminate_Err:
    Call Log.add(e_ltError,  "Class_Terminate", Err.Description)
    Resume Next
End Sub

Public Sub addElement(ByRef cronElement As ClsCron)

    myCol.add cronElement

End Sub
```

myCol is declared in a modul as public variable and is being initialized when the master object is initialized.

```
Dim myCol As Collection
...


Public Sub addElement(ByVal cronElement As ClsCron)

    myCol.add cronElement

End Sub


Dim Cron as ClsCron
    Set Cron =  new ClsCron
    'some constructors
    Cron.Init("abba","banana")
```

Here the error apears:

```
 myCronCol.addElement (Cron)
```

What I'm doing wrong? :-(

Comment: what is `myCronCol` and where is it declared? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: probably get rid of the parentheses around `(Cron)`, because that class won't have a default property/method. The parens are forcing an evaluation, which is likely raising that error because `Cron` does not implement this (default) property or method.

Comment: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692769/vba-usage-of-parentheses-for-a-method#comment99952066_56692769) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262186/vb6-pass-by-value-and-pass-by-reference/10262247#10262247) maybe.

Comment: @David Zemens myCronCol is an instance of a collection class that I have created