# VBA gives syntax error when sub requires parameter

Tags: excel, vba

As shown, `test1` calls `FillEmptyWith` but it gives me a

> Compile Error: = Expected

Could someone help?

```
Sub FillEmptyWith(Range, val)
    For Each cell In Range
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            cell.Value = val
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub
```

---

```
Sub test1()
   FillEmptyWith ((Sheets("In Force Earnix").Range("S10:S20")),"N")
End Sub
```

Comment: I would avoid using `Range` or `val` as variable names.  And don't wrap the first argument in parentheses when you call your sub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would avoid using `Range` or `val` as variable names.

And don't wrap the first argument in parentheses when you call your sub (since it will cause that range to be passed to your sub as a 2-D array instead of a Range object).

You don't need parentheses at all when calling a sub.

```
Sub FillEmptyWith(rng As Range, v)
    Dim cell as range
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) Then
            cell.Value = val
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Sub test1()
    FillEmptyWith Sheets("In Force Earnix").Range("S10:S20"),"N"
End Sub
```

Related:  [VBA: Usage of parentheses for a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692769/vba-usage-of-parentheses-for-a-method/56693168#56693168)

Answer (score 0):

As @TimWilliams noted, parenthesis causes a problem. If you prefer, you *can* use parenthesis, but only one pair:

```
Call FillEmptyWith(Sheets("In Force Earnix").Range("S10:S20"),"N")
```