# How to add option button to spreadsheet?

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button, with-statement

I am trying to put together the 'Hello, World' of a macro button that will make an option/radio button on a cell in an Excel spreadsheet, the simplest possible snippet that will do the job, so I can better understand `OptionButtons.Add` and later build on it.

Why does the following VBA code throw an error?

> "Compile error: Expected: =":

```vb
Sub BrokenOptionButtonTest()
Dim rang As Range
Set rang = Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column)
ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(rang.Left, rang.Top, rang.Width, rang.Height)
End Sub
```

Why does the following VBA code not throw an error?

```
Sub PuzzlingOptionButtonTest()
Dim rang As Range
Set rang = Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column)
With ActiveSheet.OptionButtons.Add(rang.Left, rang.Top, rang.Width, rang.Height)
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the parentheses from the first one, since you're not using the return value from `Buttons.Add`

In the second block you're using the return value as the subject of the `With` block, so no problem there.

See [VBA: Usage of parentheses for a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56692769/vba-usage-of-parentheses-for-a-method)  for example

```vb
Sub OptionButtonTest()
    With Selection.Cells(1)
        .Parent.OptionButtons.Add .Left, .Top, .Width, .Height
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something fundamental about syntax, I just didn't know what. Thank you.